# Yii1 Get options selected in dropdown when options has extra atrributes

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x, yii-form

When i add extra atrribute to options in  CHtml::dropDownList(), i am not able to set options selected.

Without adding extra atrribute to CHtml::dropDownList(), i am able to get an option selected and the code for this is

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList("rating[$i]", '', CHtml::listData(Rating::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'Description'), array('prompt' => 'Select a rating', 'options' => array($question->rating_id => array('selected' => TRUE)), 'class' => 'input-xlarge ddc hrq'));
```

But when i add extra atrribute, selected option not work, modified code is

```
 echo CHtml::dropDownList("rating[$i]", '', CHtml::listData(Rating::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'Description'), array('prompt' => 'Select a rating', 'options' => array($question->rating_id => array('selected' => TRUE), '1' => array('number' => 5), '2' => array('number' => 4), '3' => array('number' => 3), '4' => array('number' => 2), '5' => array('number' => 1), '16' => array('number' => 0)), 'class' => 'input-xlarge ddc hrq'));
```

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you want get with  ` '1' => array('number' => 5), '2' => array('number' => 4), '3' => array('number' => 3), '4' => array('number' => 2), '5' => array('number' => 1), '16' => array('number' => 0) `..?  this don't seems attribute but somethings related to the valeu of the options ..

Comment: What do you mean by "selected option not work" ? Also try selected="selected" instead of selected="true"

Comment: It gives me drop down like `<select class="input-xlarge ddc hrq" name="rating[12]" id="rating_12">
<option value="">Select a rating</option>
<option value="1" number="5">Outstanding</option>
<option value="2" number="4">Exceeds Expectation </option>
<option value="3" number="3">Meets Expectation </option>
<option value="4" number="2">Needs Improvement</option>
<option value="5" number="1">Unsatisfactory</option>
<option value="16" number="0">Not able to judge</option>
</select>`

i need number attribute to perform some ajax operation, thats why it is there

Comment: "selected option not work" means options in the drop down not getting selected, which is stored in db